# Multi-language meta description for SEO

Tags: seo, multilingual, meta-description

We run a website in Latvia in Latvian language. The thing is that the website mainly promotes free Bibles only in Russian and English languages. The Latvian audience fairy knows whether Russian or English.

So, what if we make the meta description with key words in those 3 languages (Latvian , Russian and English) so that search engines would index the website as fitting for Latvian residents who search both in Russian or English?

```
<meta name="description" content="bībele, bibele, bezmaksas 
bībele, bezmaksas bibele, pasūtīt bībele, pasutit bibele, 
библия, библия бесплатно, заказать библию, bible, free 
bible, order bible" />
```

The html tag lang property is **LV**: `<html lang="lv-LV">`

Is that correct, wise? If not, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta description should not be a list of keywords, and it should not mix different languages.

The meta description should be a sentence that describes the page to users.   It is sometimes shown in the Google search results instead of an excerpt from the page when words in the meta description match the search term.

The meta description should be written in the same language as the language of the page. So your meta description should be written in Latvian and intended to be read naturally by speakers of that language.

A good meta description might be something like this (but written in Latvian):

> Download 173 free bibles in Russian or English languages.

Using keywords in your meta description won't help your site rank better for those keywords.   Google doesn't index the words in the meta description at all.  Instead it shows it in the search results when it contains keywords that match the search term.   The reason to use keywords in the meta description is only to get the meta description to show up in the search results for the most common searches that show the page.

Comment: thank you. "it shows it in the search results when it contains keywords that match the search term" - suppose **I want the website to be indexed by Russian/English keywords from the description** or from other meta part of the site. And I do not care if meta description is shown in SE search results...

Comment: I've added keywords of 3 languages into description since I do not know **how to add meta keywords inside of WP system**...

Comment: Google ignores meta keywords and doesn't index the meta description.  If you want the page indexed for those words then you need to write text on the page that uses those words.